# Activity not getting restored after clicking notification bar

Tags: android, android-layout, service, android-mediaplayer, remoteview

I am trying to make a musicplayer in which mediaplayer is attached to a service and a notification in background keeps the playback on.

But when i click  on notification it creates a new instance of activity rather restoring it .

Here are my codes,Please check them :-

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.player);


     MusicService.mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        MusicService.mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important


startService(Explicit(getApplicationContext(),new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_SETUP)));
playSong(currentSongIndex);

}
public static void  playSong(int songIndex){
            MusicService.mPlayer.reset(); 
                    MusicService.mPlayer.setDataSource(getPathForsongname(Playlist.get(songIndex)));
                     MusicService.mPlayer.prepare();
                     MusicService.mPlayer.start();


                songTitle = Playlist.get(songIndex);
                songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);
                songArtistLabel.setText(getArtistForsongname(songTitle));
                songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                songProgressBar.setMax(100);

                updateProgressBar();//It updates the progress by using handler progress bar simply


            } 

        }
```

Now in service i am setting up foreground like this:-

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
         if (action.equals(ACTION_SETUP)){
        setupAsForeground(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.Playlist.get(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.currentSongIndex));
        }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;   }

void setUpAsForeground(String text) {

        stopForeground(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 0);
  RemoteViews r = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.notification_layout);//set your custom layout
        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        nextIntent.setAction(ACTION_SKIP);
        PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                 nextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Intent prevIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        prevIntent.setAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);

        PendingIntent pprevIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                 prevIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        playIntent.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
        PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                 playIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mSongTitle=AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.Playlist.get(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.current);
        artist=AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.getArtistForsongname(mSongTitle);
        r.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnNext, pnextIntent); 
        r.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPrevious, pprevIntent); 
        r.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlay, pplayIntent); 
        r.setTextViewText(R.id.songTitle1, mSongTitle);
        r.setTextViewText(R.id.Artist1, artist);
        r.setFloat(R.id.songTitle1, "setTextSize", 14);
        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(  
                this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(" Music Player")
        .setContentText(text)

        .setContent(r)
        .setContentIntent(pi)
                .setOngoing(true)
                  .setWhen(0)

                .setAutoCancel(false);

      startForeground(1,mBuilder.build());
    }
```

But when i destroy the activity by removing it from recent tasks.

And than click on notification bar it starts a new activity and plays song from 0:00 .

Is there anyway to restart the activity from same state ?
I tried onsaveinstance() and onrestoreinstance() nothing worked for me.

Please suggest me a way to do so.

Any help would be appreciated ...thank yu in advance :)

Comment: try with `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in activity manifest

Comment: You're resetting the media player in your `playSong(currentSongIndex);` call.

Comment: Your service's sole purpose seem to be setting a foreground notification, while your ephemeral Activity is in charge of actual play control. A better implementation is to move all music playing implementations to the service and provide methods to allow your Activity to control it and retrieve its status.

Comment: @Kai can u elaboarte a bit ?

Comment: @developer do Google search and you'll find many examples like [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778)

Answer (score 3):

Create the pending intent using the below code:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move your play() function in your service. when ever you want to play a song just start service with requires attributes like your song uri etc.